# Let's play Peg Solitaire

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

[Peg solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire) is a popular game usually played alone. The game consists of some number of pegs and a board which is divided into a grid - usually the board is not rectangular but for this challenge we will assume so.

Each valid move allows one to remove a single peg and the goal is to play in a way, such that there is a single peg left. Now, a valid move has to be in a single direction (north, east, south or east) and jump over one peg which can be removed.

### Examples

Let `.` be empty spaces on the board and numbers are pegs, the following move will move `1` one to the right and remove `2` from the board:

```
.....     .....
.12..  -> ...1.
.....     .....
```

A move will always have to jump over a single peg, so the following is **not** valid:

```
......    ......
.123.. -> ....1.
......    ......
```

Here are some valid configurations after one move each:

```
...1...        ...1...        ..71...        ..71...
.2.34.5  --->  .24...5  --->  .2....5  --->  ......5
.678...  (4W)  .678...  (7N)  .6.8...  (2S)  ...8...
.......        .......        .......        .2.....
```

### Challenge

Given an initial board configuration and some other configuration, output whether the other configuration can be reached by successively moving pegs around as described above.

### Rules

- Input will be a \$n \times m\$ matrix/list of lists/... of values indicating an empty space (eg. zero or false) or pegs (eg. non-zero or true)

  - you may assume \$n \geq 3\$ and \$m \geq 3\$
  - you may use true/non-zero to indicate empty spaces and vice-versa if it helps
- Output will be two distinct (one of the values might differ) values indicating whether the end-configuration can be reached (eg. *falsy*/*truthy*, `[]`/`[list of moves]` ..)

### Test cases

```
initial  goal -> output
[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]]  [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]] -> True
[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]]  [[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,0,0]] -> False
[[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]  [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]] -> False
[[0,0,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,0]]  [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,0]] -> False
[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]  [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]] -> False
[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]  [[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]] -> True
[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]  [[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] -> False
[[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0]]  [[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1]] -> True
[[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0]]  [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]] -> False
[[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0]]  [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]] -> True
[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]  [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]] -> False
[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]  [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]] -> False
[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]  [[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] -> True
[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]  [[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] -> True
[[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0]]  [[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0]] -> True
[[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0]]  [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] -> True
```

Comment: What happened to peg `7` in your example? Why does it vanish after `2` moves south?

Comment: @Ourous: That was just a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>184 178</s>  173 bytes

Takes input as `(initial_board)(target_board)`. Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
a=>g=b=>a+''==b|a.some((r,y)=>r.some((v,x,A,X,R)=>[-1,0,1,2].some(h=>(A=a[y+(R=~-h%2)]||0)[X=x+(h%=2)]&v>(R=a[y+R*2]||0)[h+=x+h]&&g(b,A[X]=r[x]=R[h]++)&(A[X]=r[x]=R[h]--))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTRboIwFH3fV/gitqNoy/sl8WUfQPZg0vShOIQtThbYjCZkv86qILSgAou83PSeyzmnp4UPuZfZOn3/@nZ2yVtYbKCQ4EUQgCft2QwgyOU8Sz5DhFJyxOCl1WpPDmRJVsRXPe4wQgkjrijBGDy0BMmPNvLh14mnLhZ5TjFfwcFG8RTU2tp7CjzN@M9uica2gmNhWREKyJKvBKT8IMDnsbBtbCGz5ThYPcU62WXJNpxvkwhtEOcnJ1QQVdm50nMVWEG0gmgFsQrCk8Vi8pr@hE8jyVjVKittyF7kNuuy0Zrt4oN2rdHxbOw22zhvNZ/GaHBqbWYM3GFuZ8gqU2XtZNkOiI06oCvkZtrt2mu94WvHU6L6dWjMGwOXXv9WRohR44iIZmD4qTTRPUzt6tb099gdhjti5tUbeJV71dgAtUEfDmtplqHW/wfSEeru@f8UfcE/2Jw@0rfWzBV/)

(removed the last two test cases that take too much time for TIO)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                             // main function taking the initial board a[]
  g = b =>                       // g = recursive function taking the target board b[]
    a + '' == b |                // yield a truthy result if a[] is matching b[]
    a.some((r, y) =>             // for each row r[] at position y in a[]:
      r.some((v, x, A, X, R) =>  //   for each value v at position x in r[]:
        [-1, 0, 1, 2]            //     list of directions (West, North, East, South)
        .some(h =>               //     for each direction h:
          ( A =                  //       A = a[y + dy]
            a[y + (R = ~-h % 2)] //       R = dy
            || 0                 //       use a dummy row if we're out of the board
          )[X = x + (h %= 2)]    //       h = dx, X = x + dx
          &                      //       yield 1 if there's a peg on the skipped cell
          ( R =                  //       R = target row
            a[y + R * 2]         //         = a[y + 2 * dy]
            || 0                 //       use a dummy row if we're out of the board
          )[h += x + h]          //       h = x + 2 * dx = target column
          < v                    //       yield 1 if there's no peg on the target cell
          &&                     //       and there's a peg on the source cell (0 < 1)
          g(                     //       if the above result is true, do a recursive call:
            b,                   //         pass b[] unchanged
            A[X] = r[x] =        //         clear the source and skipped cells
            R[h]++               //         set the target cell
          ) & (                  //       and then restore the board to its initial state:
            A[X] = r[x] =        //         set the source and skipped cells
            R[h]--               //         clear the target cell
          )                      //
        )                        //     end of some() over directions
      )                          //   end of some() over columns
    )                            // end of some() over rows
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 232 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
r=reverse
@[a:t=:[b,c:u]]=[[a:v]\\v<- @t]++take(a*b-c)[[0,0,1:u]];@l=[]
```

```
flip elem o\c=limit(iterate(nub o concatMap\l=[l]++[f(updateAt i p(f l))\\f<-[id,transpose],q<-f l&i<-[0..],p<- @q++(map r o@o r)q])[c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9PS8NAEMXv/RRzksRsSnrwUhuIUA9CBaHHzR6mm40u7r9uJgG/vHFrFBQEGRjm8d4Mv5FGoZut70ajwKJ2s7bBR4IjdfduYnskXB/0QKtYRzWpOKhVw3FL9ZafmNyOQtQ86Um07bQroSFRFISvKsPrUylzzitWsc0ld9uYmou5H50k7R3U0BsdQBllwbeyNtpqyjSpiKQyN57Ag/ROIj1iaNOuSad5n42hS4E7Ag0h68Hkedv2u5LrjlFENwQ/KMHOuzJ5VzoZ1XotWLjAnYsisxgggm88xPwsci5FvjoSppcT0Dfbgp3AP3slGF/mzdK/9OaX/6OEgD9P/Iz8p8X8LnuDz8NcPhzm/ZtDq@UingxS76Ody5f5pqrsBw)

This is one of the rare occasions in which I can utilize composition and currying while saving bytes.

Explained:

`@ :: [Int] -> [[Int]]` is a helper function used to generate the different potential *new* rows/columns that could result from a move being made. It avoids needing to special-case `[1,1,0:_]` by noticing that `a*b-c>0` only when `[a,b,c]=[1,1,0]`, and so `take(a*b-c)...` gives `[]` by taking `-1` or `0` elements for all configurations that aren't a valid move.

`flip elem o...` reverses the order of arguments to `elem` (making it "does x contain a y" instead of "is x a member of y") and applies the anonymous function on `c` to the first argument.

`\c=limit(iterate(nub o concatMap ...)[c])` generates every potential board that can result from the `c` by joining the current set of boards with all the moves that can happen on all of the boards and removing the duplicates, until the result stops changing.

`\l=[l]++...` prepends the board `l` to the list of all potential new boards one-move distance away, generated by applying `@` to the rows of each orientation of the board (0, 90, 180, 270-degree rotations) and replacing the corresponding changed row with the new row.